# Installing PHP on Linux: Cannot load /etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server

Tags: php, apache

I've installed PHP with `yum install php`, after that I've added the following lines in `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
....
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And after that I've copied `libphp5.so` to `/var/apache2/modules`. Then I said `/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop` and got the following error.

> httpd: Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot
>   load /etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:
>   /etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_config

Installed PHP version is `5.4.41`. OS is `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503`.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

**UPD** Apache version is 2.4.6 (64-bit), line 57 of httpd.conf is `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: Which one is line 57?

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: @Sizons the stock Apache for CentOS 7 is 2.4.6

Comment: @Eugeny89 What repo did you use to install PHP from?

Comment: That line looks fine, what is the line just above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's odd about this is that you installed PHP using yum and then went to add `php.so` to Apache. The RPM should do that for you (that's the whole idea behind package managers). In CentOS 7 the `.so` file is loaded in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` (you should have a file called something like `10-php.conf`). There should also be a `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file where your `FilesMatch` directive is added. If you are defining these twice you could be causing issues.

I would also suggest that you use a later version of PHP than 5.4 (this version will go into [End Of Life](http://php.net/eol.php) when PHP 7.0 is released later this year). If you're not using the [Remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) then I would set that up and you can get 5.5 or 5.6. I am using this myself and have not any of the issues you mention. It could also be that the version of PHP you installed is not compiled for CentOS 7 (this issue is unique to Apache 2.4). Remi does have a CentOS 7  repo.